# How rollback settings without restart Emacs?

Tags: key-bindings, magit

windows 10, emacs 26.1

In my init.el

```
(with-eval-after-load 'magit-status
  (define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") nil))
```

This disable `C-<tab>` after `magit-status` was load.
And now `C-<tab>` is disable in `magit-status`. Nice.

But suppose I want to rollback `C-<tab>` in `magit-status`. How I can do this?
Off course I can remove this code and restart Emacs. 
But has any better solution?

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `nil` in your code with the name of the function it was originally bound to and re-evaluate it. I think it's `magit-section-cycle`, so the code would be:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'magit-status
  (define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'magit-section-cycle))
```

You can evaluate just that line by placing point (the cursor) at the end of the second line and entering `C-x C-e`.

The `with-eval-after-load` form delays running the code until after `magit-status` is loaded. If you're just tweaking your settings and you want to switch your keybindings back and forth temporarily, you only need to evaluate the `define-key` form (as long as magit-status has already been loaded):

```
(define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'magit-section-cycle)
```